# conditional expectation of independent variables6

Tags: probability

I'm new to conditional expectation. I don't know how to approach this:

Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent variables with uniform distribution between $0$ to $2$.

I need to calcualte:

1)$E[XYZ|X=1]$

2) $E[XYZ+X(Y+Z)]$

In my textbook I only found that:
$E[X|Y=y]=\sum$ $xP${$X=x|Y=y$}, and also $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$.

My problam is that I don't know how to manage three variables $E[XYZ]$

Can I manipulate $E[XYZ+X(Y+Z)]=E[XYZ]+E[X(Y+Z)]$ because of independency?

Comment: You do not even need independency for that. Expectation is linear: $\mathbb E(aX+bY)=a\mathbb EX+b\mathbb EY$. Also if $X,Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Ok. But what can I do with E[XYZ?

Comment: First note that $\mathbb E[XYZ\mid X=1] =\mathbb E[1YZ\mid X=1]=\mathbb E[YZ\mid X=1]$. Then realize that the independency guarantees that the distribution of $YZ$ is not affected by the condition $X=1$ so that $\mathbb E[YZ\mid X=1]=\mathbb EYZ$. Finally we also have $\mathbb EYZ=\mathbb EY\mathbb EZ$ because $Y,Z$ are independent. You can also apply that on terms like $XYZ$.

Comment: First, thank you. second, if I have E[XYZ∣X=0] or E[XYZ∣X=2] im doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same thing.